# Ceasars Cipher in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class CeasarsCipher
def initialize text
    @text = text.split ''
end

def encrypt key
    @text = @text.each do |letter|
        key.times do
            if letter != "z"
                letter.next!
            else
                letter = "a"
            end
        end
    end
end

def printCipher
    puts @text
end
end

cipher = CeasarsCipher.new "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
cipher.encrypt 2
cipher.printCipher
```

When i run this code my output is:
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
z
z

I don't understand why there is the z 3 times. I thought about for a long time but i don't get it...
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: More Ruby/functional way of doing ROT13 Cipher: `"encrypt me".tr( ('a'..'z').to_a.join, ('a'..'z').to_a.rotate(13).join)`. See [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr) for explanation.

Comment: I second the motion to use `tr`. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645170/issue-with-ruby-decryption-method/45651671#45651671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you do `letter = "a"` you don't change the string, instead you declare a new variable.

Here is a fix using `map`:

```
def encrypt key
  @text.map! do |l|
    key.times.reduce(l) do |l|
      l == 'z' ? 'a' : l.next
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So each just iterates through an array, while map changes every item in it?